# Why does `for lst in lst:` work?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following code

```
lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
for lst in lst:
    print lst
```

gives me this output

```
foo
bar
baz
```

I would expect either an error or the following output:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

The code above is wrong and should have been

```
lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
for lst_element in lst:
    print lst_element
```

Why is it, that `python` although yields the expected output?

Comment: What's wrong if it is already generating expected output?

Comment: Why did you expect an error? Python is strongly but dynamically typed, it has no problem with you shadowing `lst`.

Comment: @ZdaR: There is nothing wrong, but I'd like to understand what happens. And coming from other languages it is somehow a surprise to me that this code works and I would like to know why/how it works.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I would have expected that the iterable gets overwritten with the first loop. So I clearly have to read and learn about shadowing.

Comment: @CoryKramer: You're right, my question addresses the same topic. But I was not able to find the question (not knowing that I need to search for iterator same name) - Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, when you say

```
for identifier in iterable:
```

first an iterator will be created from the *iterable*. So, the actual object will not be used in the looping. Then the iterator will be iterated and the current value will be bound to the name *identifier*.

Quoting the [official documentation of `for`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement),

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
          ["else" ":" suite]
```

> The *expression list* is evaluated once; it should yield an iterable object. **An iterator is created for the result of the *expression_list***. The suite is then executed once for each item provided by the iterator, in the order of ascending indices. **Each item in turn is assigned to the *target list* using the standard rules for assignments**, and then the suite is executed.

In your example, after the last iteration, `lst` will be referring to `baz`, not the list itself, because the `for` loop has bound the name `lst` to `baz` in the last iteration.

Comment: the last sentence of your answer (after the last iteration, lst will be referring to baz) was the key for me to understand. thanks a lot.